# Cordova app listed as 'webIntentFilter' under Android settings for Location permissions

Tags: android, cordova, location-services, webintents

I don't know when this occurred, but my app was always listed by `MyAppName` under the Android Phone Settings for `Location Permissions` - the settings section that specifies what apps are allowed to use location services (ie: always, only when in use, never, etc).

I discovered yesterday that in this section my app is no longer listed as `MyAppName` and is now listed as `webIntentFilter` - I was able to validate this on several Android phones, including my own.  My app icon is correct, just the name is wrong.

In my config.xml:

```
<widget id="com.myAppName" ... >
      <name>myAppName</name>
```

So, obviously some android:label: 'webIntentFilter' is overriding my config.xml app name.

I haven't a clue as to where this is originating from.  I searched my entire project folder for files with the string `webIntentFilter` in them and got 17 hits across 12 files.  But I don't know which one is causing the problem.  I looked at all of them and none of them seem to be related to Location Services so I can't determine which is the culprit.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found it....but I still have no idea how it happened, or how many revs of my app its been like this.

In projectFolder\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml was the main `<application>` section xml tag had the following:

```
<application
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:fullBackupContent="false"
      android:fullBackupOnly="false"
      android:hardwareAccelerated="true"   
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="webIntentFilter"          <----------------------------- here
      android: name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
      .....
  >
```

Changing it to: `android:label="myAppName"` fixed it.